# Point querying an azure storage table

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin

When I try this code

```
 public static async  Task<CustomerEntity> RetrieveEntityUsingPointQueryAsync(CloudTable table, string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        try
        {
            TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<CustomerEntity>(partitionKey, rowKey);
            TableResult result = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
            CustomerEntity customer = result.Result as CustomerEntity;

            if (customer != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", customer.PartitionKey, customer.RowKey, customer.Email, customer.PhoneNumber);
            }

            // Get the request units consumed by the current operation. RequestCharge of a TableResult is only applied to Azure CosmoS DB 
            if (result.RequestCharge.HasValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request Charge of Retrieve Operation: " + result.RequestCharge);
            }

            return customer;
        }
        catch (StorageException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

it says

> TableQuery Generic Type must provide a default parameterless
>   constructor   Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.StorageException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, you need to have a parameterless constructor for your `CustomerEntity` class.

Simply add the following code to your CustomerEntity class and that should take care of this problem:

```
public CustomerEntity()
{     
}
```

Comment: OMG ,it worked , cant believe it ,been 2 days seraching for an answer i am a newbie in programming though, man if i could ever see u i would give u a kiss <3

Comment: <blush/> . Eagerly waiting for that day .